# Free energy of isotropic superconductivity ($s$-wave)

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, superconductivity

As far as I know, $s$-wave superconductivity has a constant order parameter (or a gap function) $\Delta$.

Ginzburg-Landau free energy takes a form $$(\nabla \Delta)^2 + |\Delta|^2 + |\Delta|^4$$
(I neglected the coefficients)

Then, for $s$-wave, since the order parameter is constant, does the gradient term vanishes and have a constant free energy?